# Mythbusting the shell variable expansion

Tags: shell, variables, environment-variables, variable-expansion

Recently, I've heard a story, that in a shell script when it is used the variable in curly braces `${variable}` one takes its value from environment variable with the same name (if exists), but if it is used as `$variable` one takes its value from local variable as it expected (and should be).. **is that true**?

Because as I know the `$...` and `${...}` are equivalent forms and I've never suffered issues like this. Could someone say about the conditions when such situation is possible unless it is a misunderstanding from the past.

Comment: This should be almost trivial to verify yourself. No?

Comment: @MattBall I tried with several shells and was unable to reproduce, also I don't tend to think that it was just a joke

Answer (score 1):

That story is nonsense, in terms of variable scope both forms are equivalent. Here is what [the standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02) says:

> ```
> ${parameter}
> ```
>
> The value, if any, of `parameter` will be substituted.
>
> The parameter name or symbol can be enclosed in braces, which are optional except for positional parameters with more than one digit or when parameter is followed by a character that could be interpreted as part of the name. The matching closing brace will be determined by counting brace levels, skipping over enclosed quoted strings and command substitutions.
>
> If the parameter name or symbol is not enclosed in braces, the expansion will use the longest valid name (see name in the XBD specification, Glossary  ), whether or not the symbol represented by that name exists. When the shell is scanning its input to determine the boundaries of a name, it is not bound by its knowledge of what names are already defined. For example, if `F` is a defined shell variable, the command:
>
> ```
> echo $Fred
> ```
>
> does not echo the value of `$F` followed by `red`; it selects the longest possible valid name, `Fred`, which in this case might be unset.